# Android animation doesn't start when onCreate is called again

Tags: android, animation

I have an app that is working fine when the dev option Don't keep activities is ON.

When is OFF though,

every time the app goes to background and resumes, the onCreate function is called again.
In there I am re-creating the last app state.

Now the problem is that a simple animation that happens on user action, doesn't start and the animation handlers never called.

It seems like the animation is ignored. And this only happens when the activity is killed and created again.

And the weirdest part is that I have 4 animations, 2 for one imageview (opening, closing) and 2 for another imageview (opening, closing).

And this happens onmly on the opening animations.

Could you help me out?

the animation xmls (for one of the opening/closing anims)

redShow animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.1"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="800"
      /> 
  <scale android:fromXScale="0.0"
      android:toXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="0.0"
      android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:duration="800">

  </scale>
</set>
```

redHide animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.0"
      android:duration="300"
      />
  <scale android:fromXScale="1.0"
      android:toXScale="0.0"
      android:fromYScale="1.0"
      android:toYScale="0.0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:duration="300">

  </scale>
</set>
```

the code (at onCreate) where I am initialising stuff

```
red = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.red);

redHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.red_hide);
redHide.setFillAfter(true);
redHide.setAnimationListener(this);

redShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.red_show);          
redShow.setFillAfter(true);
redShow.setAnimationListener(this);
```

the handlers and the methods I am callling

```
private void showRed() {
    red.startAnimation(redShow); //this is the one that is not happening
}

private void hideRed() {
     red.startAnimation(redHide);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {   
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
}
```

G

Comment: You should really post your code

Comment: Can't help without code.  And a tip, do as little as possible in onCreate.  onResume() or onStart() are probably better places to handle this.

Comment: Are you certain (i.e. breakpoint) that startAnimation() is being called?

Comment: yep. I have added a breakpoint. It executes the line but nothing happens. And the handlers are not called.

Comment: Where do you call showRed()?

Comment: I am calling showRed() from inside the player started (AAC streamer)  handler and within a thread (I had to put it in a thread as it modifies the UI).

Comment: I found out that the animation that was running had a different ID every time the activity was created. Therefore I made them static together with the ImageView. It looks ok now but I am not sure if it's still the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things you could try are:

- init the animations in onResume() instead.
- Call clearAnimation() before you start each animation.
- Try to animate without fillAfter(), maybe the animation has been locked to it's latest state somehow.

Just some ideas..

A blinking red warning lamp went off when you wrote that you are recreating the last app state since the code you are showing to us looks just fine.